# Can you use mod_rewrite to remove user-agent

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, web, user-agent

Our application has a filter that uses the user-agent of incoming requests to redirect to our mobile site if appropriate. We have recently added a page to our web app that should be referenced by all types. We will be adding whitelist functionality to the filter in the longer term but in the short term we would like a simple way to stop the filter from triggering.

If we can remove or overwrite the user-agent from the request we will achieve our short-term aim, but this needs to be done in such a way so to avoid redeploying. Something like a mod_rewrite rule would be ideal.

Can mod_rewrite, or something similar, do the job? It would need to be a standard apache module so we don't have to do more than add a line or two of config.

**Adendum:**

Looks like we can use the following combination (or something similar)

```
SetEnvIf REQUEST_URI "special/uri/path" delete_user_agent
RequestHeader unset User-Agent env=delete_user_agent
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot do it with `mod_rewrite`: it can use `User-Agent` header in conditions, but cannot change it. What you need perhaps is [mod_headers](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_headers.html).

> This module provides directives to control and modify HTTP request and
>   response headers. Headers can be merged, replaced or removed.

The directive would probably look like this:

```
RequestHeader unset User-Agent
```

(You may need to use `early` here to process this header before `mod_rewrite` will).